# Autoresize textarea remove rows on backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have the following code for autoresizing a textarea:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea class="autoresize" id="txt" rows="2"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#txt').keydown(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      rows = parseInt($this.attr('rows'));

  // on enter, add a row
  if (e.which === 13)
    $this.attr('rows', rows + 1);

  // on backspace, remove a row -- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
  if (e.which === 8 && rows !== 2) 
    $this.attr('rows', rows - 1);
});
```

It works well, but when I hit backspace to erase a letter from a word, it also removes rows, and that's my problem.
I want it to shrink back when the user "deletes" empty rows but I don't know how to achieve it.

If you want, you can check it out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw41qknn/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the last line is empty. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/tw41qknn/1/).

```
if (e.which === 8 && rows !== 2) {
        lines = $(this).val().split('\n');

        if(!lines[lines.length - 1]) {
            $this.attr('rows', rows - 1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the length of the text you've entered (in every `keydown`) and then when you use backspace check if the last character (get it using the index from the length) is \n, only then delete row.